# How can I edit the attribute of a particular character in the body of a google doc with script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'd like to change the font size of particular characters in the body of a google doc using Script. The following very simple code edits the entire body.

```
function myFunction() {

var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
body.setFontSize(14);

}
```

How can I select particular characters in the body, or groups of characters, and edit the font size?

So far, I've tried everything in classes "body" and "text", but nothing seems to fit the bill. I suppose I'm looking for something like "body.setFontSize(5,7)", where the first number is an index and the second the end point for the font edit.

Thanks

Comment: What are the conditions to edit the font size? Maybe you are referring to specific words or those texts are highlighted, you can make use of those conditions. Or you just want to edit those in a particular position in the doc? If possible please share a copy of your doc (remove sensitive data if any), and clearly specify what you want to edit, so we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I just want to change a particular position. For example, character 4. Why? I'm writing a routine that makes typed text look more like handwritten text. This can be accomplished by moving through the document, letter by letter, and making changes to the font size or face. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification? In this case, the method of `setFontSize(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, size)` is used.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const searchText = "sample"; // Please set the search text.

  const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  let find = body.findText(searchText);
  while (find) {
    find.getElement().asText().setFontSize(find.getStartOffset(), find.getEndOffsetInclusive(), 14);
    find = body.findText(searchText, find);
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the text of `searchText` is searched and the font size of the searched text is changed to `14`.

#### Reference:

- [setFontSize(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, size)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setfontsizestartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-size)